# Mean standardise variables and add to dataframe

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I would like to standardise several variables in a dataset (to mean=0 and standard deviation=1) and to then add these variables to the dataframe with the suffix '_sd' added to the variable name. I have tried to edit the code for log transforming below but that didn't work. Thank you!

```
data("mtcars")

#This is what the code looks like manually
mtcars$disp_sd <-  scale(disp, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)

#Code which works for log transformation
log.outcomes <- c("disp", "hp", "wt", "qsec")
data <- mtcars %>%
mutate_at(vars(one_of(log.outcomes)), funs(log = log(.))) %>%
rename_at(vars(contains("_log")), funs(paste0("log", gsub("_log", "", .))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
log.outcomes <- c("disp", "hp", "wt", "qsec")
data <- mtcars %>%
           mutate_at(vars(one_of(log.outcomes)), funs(sd = scale(., center=TRUE, scale=TRUE)))
```

Comment: That's only assuming that elements in `log.outcomes` are all present

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work for me:

```
dat <- mtcars %>%
  mutate_at(vars(disp, hp, wt, qsec), funs(sd =  (. - mean(.)) / sd(.)))
```